# How to make twitter boostrap "colspan=2"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and I have a form. I need the first row to be like "colspan=2".
I hope I am clear enough.. how can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        I Need this row to be like "colspan=2" in table td
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="my_input">field name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="my_input" name="my_input"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="my_input">field name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="my_input" name="my_input"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3j7QP/7/

Answer (score 1):

Like that: http://jsfiddle.net/3j7QP/16/ ?

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 80px; background: red;">
            xxx
        </div>

        <div class="control-group" style="float:left;">
            <label class="control-label" for="my_input">field name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="my_input" name="my_input"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" style="float:left;">
            <label class="control-label" for="my_input">field name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="my_input" name="my_input"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was your typo. :) If not, I don't see any problems: http://jsfiddle.net/3j7QP/35/ Or I haven't understood you?

Comment: I hoped the alignment will be to the left, above the leftier label. Not center or completely left..

Comment: Then you have to modify CSS file. Or use some ugly solution like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3j7QP/55/